# Not able to Read Locked Table in side of a nested INSERT statement

Tags: mysql

I am doing some data merge logic. Firstly I am locking my tables then running a few simple queries to populate my new schema. But when I run the query I get a Error Code: 1100. Table 'MyReadTable' was not locked with LOCK TABLES.

I've tried Surrounding my code in

```
SET SESSION TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED;
// My Query
SET SESSION TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL REPEATABLE READ;
```

But this Does not work.

I have also tried using [EXPLAIN or EXPLAIN EXTENDED](https://dbamohsin.wordpress.com/2012/07/02/nolock-equivalent-in-mysql/), but it didn't tell me much.

EXAMPLE:

```
LOCK TABLES
    `MyWriteTable` WRITE,
    `MyReadTable` READ;

/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `MyWriteTable` DISABLE KEYS */;
INSERT INTO MyWriteTable
SELECT * FROM
    (
        SELECT id, name, 53 AS unique_id
        FROM MyReadTable
        WHERE name LIKE '%test%'
        UNION
            SELECT id, name, 89 AS unique_id
            FROM MyReadTable
            WHERE name LIKE '%example%'
    ) TempTable;
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `MyWriteTable` ENABLE KEYS */;
```

Is there a way around this problem using the UNIONs inside of the nested INSERT, while still being able to use the LOCK functionality?

The reason I am Locking the tables, is because I am going to be pulling live data for a data migration and I need the data to not change in between inserts, there will be 50+ inserts and if data gets pushed into one of the tables it will most likely mess things up. This is my reason for using the LOCK functionality.

Comment: Why do you need to use LOCK TABLES? That's generally not needed if you use a transactional storage engine like InnoDB. It's a holdover from the days when MyISAM was the default storage engine.

Comment: Agree with Bill. You do not need to use locks here usually. ALso, you do not need UNION in the example as you can use OR in WHERE clause. However, if you still need to use union and locks for some reason (that was not mentioned here for simplicity), you can try to add alias to second instance of MyReadTable (MyReadTable as MyReadTable2) and lock it for reading using the alias.

Comment: @BillKarwin sorry, yes I do need a Union but I simplified my example in a way that it doesn't seem like I do, So, I tweaked it to match what I'm actually trying to accomplish more closely.  So, what you're suggesting is for me to LOCK `MyReadTable` AS TempTable READ;  ??? In my example I didn't use an alias are you saying that one is required for it to work? When I used an alias it didn't work for me, but I'm not sure if your saying TempTable needs to be referenced or not?

Comment: I'm saying the first statement, where you write `LOCK TABLES <whatever>;` -- take that out completely. You don't need it. If you use InnoDB tables, you can rely on its ACID behavior already. The other statement, `INSERT ... SELECT ... ;` is fine.

Comment: You also don't need to disable or re-enable keys. Just let the indexes be updated normally as it inserts data into MyWriteTable.